# $\overline{A \oplus B} = \overline{A} \oplus \overline{B}$ for orthogonal subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $A,B \subset X$, where $X$ is a Hilbert space, be orthogonal subspaces.
>   Do we have
>   $$\overline{A \oplus B} = \overline{A} \oplus \overline{B}, \tag{1}$$
>   where $\oplus$ denotes the orthogonal direct sum.

---

Some background: When discussing pseudoinverses of linear operator on Hilbert spaces we defined the domain of the pseudoinverse $T^+$ of an operator $T: X \to Y$, as $D(T^+) = \text{ran(T)} \oplus \text{ran}(T)^{\perp}$.
A remark states that this domain is dense as $\overline{D(T^+)} = \overline{\text{ran}(T)} \oplus \text{ran(T)}^{\perp} = Y$.
I want to the reasoning behind this statement.
If $(1)$ would hold, the result would follow, as $\text{ran}(T)^{\perp}$ is already closed, i.e. $\overline{\text{ran}(T)^{\perp}} = \text{ran}(T)^{\perp}$.

---

If yes, can you please provide me a hint to proof it.

**My thoughts:**
"$\subset$": Let $(a_n + b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset A \oplus B$ with $(a_n + b_n)_n \to c \in \overline{A \oplus B}$.
Now we have to show that $c = a + b$ with $ a \in \overline{A}$ and $b \in \overline{B}$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your main highlighted question, (1) is not true for general topological vector spaces, as is shown by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494852/overline-v-overline-v-1-oplus-overline-v-2?rq=1) answer.

What we do have though, for any Hilbert space $H$, is if $A,B\subset H$ are orthogonal, then $\bar A\oplus \bar B \subset \overline{A\oplus B}$. This is simple to prove. We first note that the continuity of the inner product means that if $A$ is orthogonal to $B$ then $\bar A$ is orthogonal to $\bar B$. Now take $x\in \bar A\oplus \bar B $, which by the above implies $x=a+b$ with $a\in \bar A$ and $b\in\bar B$. We have sequences $(a_n)\subset A$ converging to $a$ and $(b_n)\subset B$ converging to $b$. Clearly $x=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n+b_n$ using the standard add and subtract trick in the norm, which finishes the proof, because $(a_n+b_n)\subset A\oplus B$.

This is enough for your problem, because as you note $Y=\overline{\operatorname{ran}(T)}\oplus \operatorname{ran}(T)^{\perp}=\overline{\operatorname{ran}(T)}\oplus \overline{\operatorname{ran}(T)^{\perp}}\subset\overline{D(T^+)}$.